# How to allow this code within a Chrome Packaged App without violating CSP?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

The first in the console is marked as an 'unsafe-eval'. How do I change it so that it can be evaluated?

**index.js:**

```
function testForFunction(str) {
return function () { result(typeof eval(str) == "function"); }
```

The error in this instead is not specified in the console.. The console only says that violates the Content Security Policy.

**index.js:**

```
function loadTestFrame(cb, src) {
if (!testFrame) { testFrame = createTestFrame(); }
frameLoadCallback = cb;

src = src || 4;

if (typeof src == "number") {
  var pgs = [];
  for (var i = 1, ii = src; i <= ii; ++i) {
    pgs.push("<div>Page "+i+"</div>");
  }
  var divStyle = [
    "display:inline-block",
    "line-height:"+testFrameSize+"px",
    "width:"+testFrameSize+"px"
  ].join(";");
  src = "javascript:'<!DOCTYPE html><html>"+
    '<head><meta name="time" content="'+(new Date()).getTime()+'" />'+
    '<style>div{'+divStyle+'}</style></head>'+
    '<body>'+pgs.join("")+'</body>'+
    "</html>'";
}

testFrame.src = src;
}
```

I know that there are ways to relax the default policy, but if possible I would prefer to don't use them..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a different CSP, you need to use a sandboxed page (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox).

Comment: You're right.. In another instance would work, in my case it does not work because of a worker script error.. Thank you anyway!!